# Overriding primary-btn color in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For a specific button on my webpage, I want to change the color. I have my own second stylesheet, listed second in the header.

```
      <button class=" btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle school-options" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a School
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Add your school</a></li>
      </ul>
```

So I added the class `.school-options`, and put it on the second stylesheet, and then set the background-color to red.

```
.school-options {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Why doesn't this work? What is the solution?

Comment: The Bootstrap library probably has higher-priority (_i.e._, specificity) from the `btn btn-primary` classes. One of the reasons I dislike using pre-made CSS libraries like Bootstrap is that, to add custom styles that override those of the library, it's often necessary to use the `!important` CSS flag -- a terrible practice that often leads to a CSS hell of trying to get progressively more specific selectors each using the `!important` exception/rule. But to answer your question, you might do `.school-options { background-color: red !important; }`

Comment: load your custom css file after loading bootstrap css. Otherwise you won't get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `!important` , you can simply fix this with changing state order of the css libraries, call the `stylesheet` below the `bootstrap` css like

```
// call bootstrap first

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

// then call the custom style , this will override the bootstrap css

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

check with demo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
.school-options {
 background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class=" btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle school-options" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a School <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Add your school</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

sometime you have to make it important

button.school-options {

```
background-color:red !important;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

**(!important)** class is used to overwrite existing styles.
**Hierarchy CSS** also used to specify specific CSS Styles.

```
btn.school-options {

background-color:red !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is some updated code in the fiddle, where I have used the `!important` with you custom class in custom css file.

However load your custom css file after loading bootstrap css. Otherwise you won't get the desired result.

**HTML**

```
<button class=" btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle school-options" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a School
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Add your school</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.school-options {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/pfm2q7s6/1/)